# Strange iframe appeared on my website "posible malware?"

Tags: php, iframe, malware

suddenly I found strange code of iframe appeared on my cms and I've scanned my website and files for this code but couldn't find it.

here it is:

```
<iframe src="http://c.sharethis.mgr.consensu.org/v1.0/cmp/portal.html" id="st_gdpr_iframe" style="width: 0px; height: 0px;"></iframe>
```

is it a possible malware or virus or what?

Comment: check the javascript files. may be you are using one of the scripts that's manually inserting the code

Answer (score 1):

The plugin "Simple Share Buttons Adder" also adds that iframe. A workaround to avoid it, is adding this line in your custom CSS:

```
#st_gdpr_iframe {display: none!important;}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this before.

it could be added by javascript dynamically.
it could be in the content, if it is a CMS
it could be in the code or templates in plain text
it could be base64_encoded string in the code or template. (search for base64_decode will appear as random character string)
it could be some other way I haven't come across.

search the database for the string or the url, 
search the file and templates for the string or the url
search both again for 'base64_decode'

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that it was caused by the google analytics plugin. Deleted the plugin and the iframe disappeared.